# Can I ask 'what your name is?'

Tags: questions, inversion, subordinate-clauses, interrogatives

Can I ask:

> 1. *'What your name is?'*

instead of,

> 2. *'What is your name?'*

Is #1 grammatically correct?

Comment: Agreed.  But I answered it anyway, darn me.

Comment: "what your name is" is not a question phrase. It could be used like "I was wondering **what your name is**".

Comment: You can, however, say `"May I ask what your name is?"` This is a slightly more formal expression than `What is your name.`

Answer (score 4):

We cannot say:

- <del>What your name is?</del>

Let's see why. Maybe if we don't hear what somebody said, we can use an echo question:

- Your name is *what*?

Another name for this type of question is an *in situ* question. We use the word *what* to show which word we didn't hear, or which word we don't know. This is a question, but it uses the same word order as a normal sentence:

- Your name is Bob.

We usually don't make questions like this. We usually move the *wh-* word to the front of the sentence when we make a question:

- What blah blah blah blah?
- Who blah blah blah blah?
- Where blah blah blah blah?

If the *wh-* word needs to move to the front of the question, then we also need to change the order of some other words. We change the subject and the auxiliary verb. Let's look at the in situ question again  to see what the subject and the auxiliary verb are:

- Your name is XXXX?

The auxiliary verb here is *is*. The verb *BE* is always an auxiliary verb, even when it is the only verb. In normal, canonical, sentences the subject is the noun phrase before the auxiliary. Here the subject is *your name*.

If we want to make the question with *what* at the beginning of the question, then we need to invert, to change round, the subject and the auxiliary like this:

- What [is] [your name]?
- What is your name?

If we do not invert the subject and the auxiliary, the sentence is ungrammatical:

- *<del>What your name is?</del>  (wrong).

Note that the order of the phrases in the sentence is:

- What (complement), is (verb), your name (subject)

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: The verb "to be" _can_ serve as an auxiliary verb, but it doesn't in "Your name is Bob". There, it's just an ordinary verb. A verb is only auxiliary when it "helps" another verb in the sentence by indicating something about modality, tense, voice, aspect, etc. For example, in "Your name will be Bob", "will" is an auxiliary verb and "be" is the main verb.

Comment: @BenKovitz That's a pretty mid-twentieth century view there ;) Modern grammars such as the CaGEL and the best of the others view auxiliaries as a class of words defined by syntactic properties, not semantic ones. Although I know some writers still stick to a semantic description, it seems hard to justify when looking at the syntactic facts. Here's a couple of posts where I've laid out the arguments about why *BE* is an auxiliary [NICE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209132/is-helper-verb-old-school/209189#209189)  ...

Comment: @BenKovitz ... and [the end end of this post too](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204950/pronoun-usage-and-conjugation/205006#205006). Would like to know your thoughts ... ?

Comment: I also understand auxiliary verbs to be defined by their syntactic properties, such as their helping another verb, called the main verb. With the traditional (and still ordinary) definition of _auxiliary verb,_ it's very easy to explain the main rules of English, like "In a question or a negation, verbs other than **be** need an auxiliary verb, but **be** doesn't." Redefining _auxiliary_ so that a separate main verb isn't needed might or might not serve a general theory of linguistics, but I think it causes useless confusion for people just trying to learn English.

Comment: @BenKovitz Au contraire, imo, it makes life much easier. For starters, you need a special case of "helping" for your definition of aux. And it needs to be different from "going to" etc. Also, think about how to explain where to put "never" in a normal sentence. You'll need three or four rules plus exceptions. We only need one rule with no exceptions!

Comment: What's the rule? I'm usually skeptical of unifying rules that are technically correct but expressed in terms of deep, subtle concepts. I think people normally understand complex things in terms of a "normal way" expressed in shallow concepts plus exceptions and competing concerns—even when there's an elegant way to lump all that into one proposition (not just in grammar but in everything). But maybe your rule is an exception to that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's grammatically correct, because I have never seen anybody to ask someone's name by saying like this. What is your name?

In my opinion, it's breaking grammar rule of interrogative sentences, because we have to put verb 'to be' (is, am, are) after the interrogative words (What, Who, Where, How, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

No matter what tense is in question, the form of English question is always the same:

```
AUXILIARY VERB + NOUN + MAIN VERB

(does          +  she  + work)
```

Question words come at the beginning and the DO NOT change the form of the question or its word order.

When there is a verb BE which usually consists of one word, then we move it to the place of auxiliary verb and the form then looks

```
VERB + NOUN

(is  + she ) OK/fine/nice/happy/...
```

So, "what your name is" is incorrect because its form is `"question word + noun + main verb"`

To respect the rule you have to ask

what + is + your + name

Now, the construction "what your name is" exists and we use it in the indirect question. For example,

```
Can you tell me...  
I wonder...  
May I know...  
I would like to know...  

*...what your name is*?
```

Answer (score 0):

**What your name is?** is ungrammatical. You must say **What is your name?**

The reason you cannot say **What your name is?** is because that word order makes the listener hear **what** as a relative pronoun. A listener hears **What your name is?** not as a question, but as a fragment of a sentence like this one:

> I know what your name is.

In this sentence, the word **what** functions as a relative pronoun: it makes **what your name is** into the object of **know**. The interrogative pronouns *what, who, whom, whose, what, where,* and *when* can also function as relative pronouns. The word order tells the listener which role the interrogative/relative pronoun is playing.

---

Here are some examples to illustrate how the word order changes (or stays the same) when you switch between declarative statement, relative clause, and question:

> 1. Your name is Jamius. / I know what your name is. / What is your name?
> 2. Terry is ready now. / I see who is ready now. / Who is ready now?

In line 1, the word order reverses to form a question, because **what** stands for a subject-complement or object. In line 2, the word order is the same in all three sentences because **who** stands for the subject.

> 3. Whose name is Jamius?

In line 3, the question's word order is the same as the declarative sentence, since **Whose name** corresponds to the subject of the declarative sentence.

There are some other important things to know about English questions, like what to do with auxiliary verbs, the need to add an auxiliary verb (usually **do**) when the verb is anything other than **be**, and the fact that you can use the word order of a declarative sentence to make a question express surprise or emphasis (for example, **Your name is *WHAT??***). But the above explains why **What your name is?** doesn't work as a question in English.

Comment: But in the usual canonical question version of "You punched who?", The subject will still come before the verb 'punched'! :) "*Who did **you punch***"

Comment: @Araucaria *Punch* is not the verb *be*. I tried to indicate in the last paragraph that verbs other than *be* require an auxiliary when made into questions, without complicating the answer so much it would overwhelm a beginner. I'd add a link to a similar answer that explains how to use those verbs in questions. Do you know of one?

Comment: "*English declarative statements normally put the subject before the verb. For example, in 'Your name is Jamius', the subject is 'your name' and the verb is 'is'.

English questions normally put the subject after the verb (except as explained below).*" I think that could mislead quite a bit ... :) You might want to tweak it a bit. [Of course, there is a simpler explanation but it involves a principled use of the term *aux* ...] :D

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks. I just made a small tweak. But now I'm thinking that my overall attempt to address "when the normal word order reverses in a question and when it doesn't" has drowned out the main point. Rethinking…

Comment: @Araucaria OK, I just rewrote nearly all of it, focusing as narrowly as I could on the original question. It's still longer and more jargon-laden than I'd like, though. :(

Comment: *"In this sentence, the word **what** functions as a relative pronoun:"* <== Er, "what" is a relative pronoun?

Comment: @F.E. I tried to explain it in the rest of the sentence you quoted from. Clearly I failed. As much as I'm trying to avoid grammar terminology, I'm currently thinking that "relative pronoun" is unavoidable. Can you think of another way to refer to the "subordinate-clause-introducing role" of who/what/where/when/why without turning the answer into a grammar glossary?

Comment: Consider: "My name is Tom" --> "Your name is what?" --> "I know [what your name is]." --> which has a paraphrase like: I know the answer to the question 'What is your name?'

Comment: @F.E. I think I follow your example, but now I'm not sure what your point is. Did you have a question or suggestion, or did you find an error or something unclear?

Comment: In my examples, the word "what" is an interrogative word (not a relative word).

Comment: @F.E. Now I think I understand. In "I know what your name is", **what** functions as a relative pronoun, not an interrogative pronoun. Notice that it doesn't ask a question. It introduces a relative clause, where it stands for the subject-complement of **is**. It's an interrogative pronoun in your other examples.

Comment: A relative "what" is found in relative clauses, while an interrogative "what" is found in interrogative clauses. My examples used interrogative clauses--this includes the example: "I know [what your name is]."

Comment: @F.E. Sorry, I still don't understand. "I know what your name is" sounds to me like a statement, not a question. What do you intend the square brackets to mean?

Comment: The stuff inside the square brackets is a subordinate interrogative clause.

Comment: @F.E. OK, now I think I understand. Why do you think **what your name is** in "I know what your name is" is interrogative?

Comment: I just showed it in a previous comment: *Consider: "My name is Tom" --> "Your name is what?" --> "I know [what your name is]." --> which has a paraphrase like: I know the answer to the question 'What is your name?'*

Comment: *"The interrogative pronouns what, who, whom, whose, what, where, and when can also function as relative pronouns. The word order tells the listener which role the interrogative/relative pronoun is playing."* <== That is wrong. Interrogative words and relative words are not the same words.

Comment: @F.E. Do you think "I know what your name is" is a statement or a question?

Comment: Perhaps you could put in your answer post an excerpt (and maybe a link) to a vetted grammar source that supports your idea about relative and interrogative words.

Comment: Do you know what a subordinate interrogative clause looks like?

Comment: @F.E. I'm deliberately not citing sources because I'd like the reader to understand first-hand what is going on. I see a lot of citing of rules and sources and highly technical language as if learning grammar were something like making a legal argument in a court of law, something only highly trained specialists can do. I don't want to contribute to that. Or at least, I'd like to provide an alternative.

Comment: The problem is that the grammar that you are opining is incorrect. For one thing, interrogative words and relative words are not the same. This site has many EFL learners on it, and people who want to learn grammar. Many of them might get misled by what you are stating in your post.

Comment: @F.E. I didn't say that interrogative and relative pronouns were _all_ the same. I listed some pronouns that can play both roles. If there's a less confusing way to explain it, though, I'm all for it.

Comment: @F.E. If you're doubting whether "relative pronoun" is a common term for pronouns that introduce relative clauses, it's easy to find books that use this terminology. Some examples: [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=f6IuAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA49), [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=CqOYAYFWHf4C&pg=PA79), [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=j4yE7y5c_NoC&pg=PA26), [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=agKE2K6GsvkC&pg=PA53). There must be hundreds more. Most native speakers learn the term "relative pronoun" by high school, even though most forget what it means.

Comment: @F.E. BTW, I understand "subordinate interrogative clause" to be a technical term used mostly by linguists, not well known to most laypeople. I thought it meant the bolded text in sentences like these: "I don't know **if my name is Rumpelstiltskin**" and "**Whether the price goes up or down**, I come out ahead." I just googled, though, and it appears that some linguists are using the term more broadly, with some variation among sources, but some indeed include your example. This sounds to me like a dangerously confusing term to use with EFL learners. What do you think?